# Converting Fastq files to Fasta files on Ubuntu

Tags: fasta, genome, sequence-analysis, fastq, linux

I am new to bioinformatics and programming. I tried to convert my fastq files to fasta file, but got this. What could be wrong?

```
(base) jszheng@Greater:~/seqtk$ seqtk seq -a KF0124_1_1.fastq > KF0124_1_1.fasta
[E::stk_seq] failed to open the input file/stream.
```

Answer (score 2):

*Answer from @haci, converted from comment:*

You should run your command within that directory (the directory where the fastq file is), this does not seem to be the case as far as I see. Alternatively you can provide the absolute path of your fastq file.

`cd` into the directory where the fastq file is (you should be able to see your file of interest when you type `ls`) and then run the command in your question:

```
cd ./genome_diirt
seqtk seq -a KF0124_1_1.fastq > KF0124_1_1.fasta
```

Alternatively you can provide the absolute path of your fastq file:

```
seqtk seq -a ./genome_diirt/KF0124_1_1.fastq > ./genome_diirt/KF0124_1_1.fasta
```